# Magento-Set latest products to Email template

Tags: magento-1.4

In my magento site I have to give the functionality to send invitation mail to friends.
This Email includes name of person who is sending invitation and latest sales(configure products )images dynamically.
The email template I have set under admin->transaction email.

Now how can I set both dynamic data for the mail template?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into one of the templates showing dynamic data in

> app/locale/en_US/template/email

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I didn't find there to fetch latest products items